# Creating Exceptions for Test Scores class

Tags: java, exception

I've created a class named TestScores which has a method that gets the average of test numbers I have in an array. I then need to create an InvalidTestScore exception class and rewrite my TestScores class to be able to throw the InvalidTestScore exception. I thougt I was doing everything right, but I get an "actual and formal arguments differ in length error". I'm new to programming so I needs helps

```
public  int getAverage() throws InvalidTestScore
    {

        int total = 0;

        int average = 0;

        for(int index = 0; index < scores.length; index++)
        {
            total += scores[index]; 

            average = total/scores.length;


                try
                {
                    if(scores[index] < 0 || scores[index] > 100)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidTestScore("Index is " + index + " Score is " + scores[index]);
                    }
                }
                catch(InvalidTestScore e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

        }  
        return average;
    }
```

// This is my InvalidTestScore class, which is in a separate file

```
 public class InvalidTestScore extends Exception
    {
    public InvalidTestScore()
    {
        super("Error: Test scores must range from 0 to 100");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies here

```
throw new InvalidTestScore("Index is " + index + " Score is " + scores[index]);
```

In your exception class, your Exception constructor takes no parameter. But you are sending a string as a parameter. So either do not add a String in the above line of code, or do this in the class

```
 public class InvalidTestScore extends Exception
 {
     public InvalidTestScore(String msg)
     {
         super(msg);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you programming wizard, much appreciated

Comment: Stop it you.. *blushes*.. Also, please accept the comment if it answered your question.. :)